# How to join datasets on similar characters?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two datasets that I want to join on `book`  column. However, the book names are a bit different from the first dataset. It seems there is no clear pattern, but the only condition would be this: the book names in `df1` is a subset of the book names `df2`. Would you have any suggestion to join them?

```
df1 <- tribble(
  ~book, ~sales, 
  "a",   100,
  "bakora",    60,
  "c",  40,
)
```

```
df2 <- tribble(
  ~book, ~sales, 
  "a.com",   100,
  "bakorade",    60,
  "c.zi",    60,
)
```

Comment: Depends on how you want to match.  In the first data, you have one letter 'a', that should match to 'a.com' e.g. `stringdist_inner_join(df1, df2, by = 'book')` returns the second row based on distance methods

Comment: Do you think there would be a way to build a condition like if the book name in df1 is in df2, join them? @akrun

Comment: In your example, all 3 in book are some way matching i.e. a with a.com, bakora with bakorade and c with c.zi

Comment: Thanks for the fuzzyjoin library, but it gave the zero overlap. @akrun

Comment: For me the `stringdist_inner_join` is returning the second row, but you can always make some changes with `max_dist`

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot @akrun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `stringdist`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_inner_join(df1, df2, by = 'book')
```